# NestedScrollView Breaks With Nested Navigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a NestedScrollView with SliverAppBar (headerSliverBuilder) and ListView (body) widgets.
I switched to NestedScrollView instead of CustomScrollView so that the ListView and SliverAppBar are scrolled as one.

My aim is to have the body a nested Navigation that switches around between different ListView widgets. However, this negates what was achieved with the NestedScrollView.

Are there any solutions?

```
            NestedScrollView(
            controller: scrollController,
            headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  collapsedHeight: _collapsedHeight,
                  expandedHeight: expandedHeight,
                  flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    return FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                        centerTitle: true,
                        title: NavBar(),
                        background: AppBarBackground());
                  }),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: GalleryGrid() //this is a widget that extends listview, and which I wish to replace with nested router
        ),
```

Comment: My current workaround: I set the physics property for all pages to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(). The body must have a widget with a fixed length, so I wrap the navigator with a widget with height property whose state I change depending on the current page displayed. Passing the BuildContext to the pages didn't work for me. This is not ideal for responsive design, but a functioning workaround nonetheless.